# How can I add an integer to an existing integer in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is what I have so far, it's very incomplete:

```
list1=[0,0,0,0,0]
check=True
while check:

    num=int(input("Which candidate are you voting for?: "))

    if num==1:

    elif num==2:

    elif num==3:

    elif num==4:

    elif num==5:

    elif num==-1:
        check=False
        for i in range(5):
            print(i+1)
    else:
        print("out of bounds")
```

I want to make it so you can vote for a candidate ranging from `1-5` until you decide to stop, and at the end, it will show the results of the vote. To do this I want to add 1 to the existing number of the list, for example if you input "2" then the list becomes `0,1,0,0,0` and then if you input "2" again it becomes `0,2,0,0,0`.

I also want the program to say the greatest number of the list so it tells you the winning candidate.

How can I add to an existing number in a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list indexing:

```
candidates = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
index = input()
index = int(index)
candidates[index] += 1
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. First of all, input returns string, second..if user wants to vote for 2 Nd candidate,and inputs 2, this code,if input converted to introduce, will update value of third candidate